# I need to delete a subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, document, subdocument

This is my structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf3ba71616b871600000c"),
    "components" : [
        {
            "type" : "text",
            "text_type" : "subtitle",
            "pos_x" : 198.384521484375,
            "pos_y" : 114.43489074707031,
            "content" : "New subtitle",
            "font" : "",
            "font_size" : "",
            "color" : "",
            "bold" : false,
            "italic" : false,
            "underlined" : false,
            "rotation" : 0,
            "scale" : 0,
            "custom_css" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf3c171616b871600000d")
        },
        {
            "type" : "text",
            "text_type" : "title",
            "pos_x" : 198.384521484375,
            "pos_y" : 114.43489074707031,
            "content" : "New title",
            "font" : "",
            "font_size" : "",
            "color" : "",
            "bold" : false,
            "italic" : false,
            "underlined" : false,
            "rotation" : 0,
            "scale" : 0,
            "custom_css" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf3c371616b871600000e")
        },
        {
            "type" : "text",
            "text_type" : "title",
            "pos_x" : 279.32373046875,
            "pos_y" : 265.3794403076172,
            "content" : "New title",
            "font" : "",
            "font_size" : "",
            "color" : "",
            "bold" : false,
            "italic" : false,
            "underlined" : false,
            "rotation" : 0,
            "scale" : 0,
            "custom_css" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf44471616b871600000f")
        },
        {
            "type" : "text",
            "text_type" : "subtitle",
            "pos_x" : 55.32373046875,
            "pos_y" : 35.37944030761719,
            "content" : "New subtitle",
            "font" : "",
            "font_size" : "",
            "color" : "",
            "bold" : false,
            "italic" : false,
            "underlined" : false,
            "rotation" : 0,
            "scale" : 0,
            "custom_css" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf44571616b8716000010")
        },
        {
            "type" : "image",
            "file" : "",
            "external_url" : "",
            "size" : 40,
            "pos_x" : 0,
            "pos_y" : 0,
            "rotation" : 0,
            "scale" : 0,
            "custom_css" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011")
        }
    ],
    "number" : 0,
    "pos_x" : 0,
    "pos_y" : 0,
    "presentation_id" : 46,
    "rotation_x" : 0,
    "rotation_y" : 0,
    "rotation_z" : 0,
    "scale" : 1
}
```

I need to delete a subdocument, in this case the "component" which has an _id equals to "52ebf4d971616b8716000011".

I've tried with this:

```
db.slides.update({"components._id": ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011")},
{$pull: {"components._id": ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011"}})
```

But it doesn't work, the document remains the same.

Comment: Forget it. I asked myself. The problem was in the $pull structure:
    db.slides.update({"components._id":     ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011")},
    {$pull: {"components": { "_id": ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011") }}})

Comment: Could you post what you ended-up doing to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted update doesn't work because you're trying to pull from `components._id` (which isn't an array), instead of pulling from `components` (which is an array) based on `_id` (which is the field by which you're trying to pull documents).

You should change your query to:

```
db.slides.update(
  { 'components._id': some-id }, 
  { $pull: { components: { _id: some-id } } });
```

as @BryceAtNetwork23 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.slides.update( {"components._id": ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011")},
{$pull: {components: {"_id": ObjectId("52ebf4d971616b8716000011")}}}, false, false)
```

Comment: An upvote from me because you were the first to answer correctly.